# Erratic results from filters.normal in PDAL?

Tags: lidar, las, aspect, pdal

Given this roof structure:

[image: roofpointcloud]

I get the following output for the `normalx`, after using:

```
{
         "type":"filters.normal",
         "knn":8
},
```

[image: point normalx]

(orange to purple : -1 to 1)

Comparable situation for `normaly` and `normalz`.

Where I was expecting homogeneous colored roofplanes, I get a mixed-up situation, where the values appear to be sometimes flipped to the negative.

It seems to me there are some artifacts here based on the laser scan-line, considering the flipping of the normal on the same roof plane.

I cannot wrap my head around what happens here. Ideas?

The purpose of this work is to get the slope and aspect from the roofplanes. I can get the slope correct by taking the absolute values of `normalz` (slope will never pass the 90 degrees) but this is not an option for calculating the aspect it seems.

The resulting point set can be downloaded [here](http://research.geodan.nl/sites/tomt/output.las).

Comment: Could you explain how did you do atan2d in pdal please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After all, it made sense.
A flat plane can have 2 normals. In this case, the slight wobble of the rotating sensor made some points a little above and some points below the average plane. Hence the kind of artifacts you see.

#### Solution:

Since we know a roof always has an upward pointing normal, we can check that whenever the normalz is negative, we flip the normalx and normaly.  `if normalz < 0 { normalx = -1 * normalx,normaly = -1 * normaly }`

The resulting aspect `atan2d(normaly,normalx)` now looks like this:
[image]

Comment: A note to follow up that this automatic flipping capability was added to PDAL and will be available for the 1.6 release going forward. https://github.com/PDAL/PDAL/issues/1638